# Allow sudo over SSH while forbidding TTY login

Tags: ssh, user-management, passwd

I want to lock users from local login (keyboard and monitor), but still allow remote logging with SSH.

Easily achievable with `passwd -l` and `ssh-copy-id`.

But what about `sudo`? I want to keep password for `sudo`, but not for local access.

edit: system is running on Ubuntu Server 18.04.3 64bit

Comment: What operating system version? sudo and ssh work on practically all the UNIXes and more, but the auth and console config is different.

Answer (score 0):

edit [/etc/access.conf](https://linux.die.net/man/5/access.conf)

Add...

```
-: ALL EXCEPT root tty1 tty2 tty3 tty4 tty5 tty6
```

(Not tested in the systemd world - YMMV)